# Spacing / gap between two col-sm-6 inside an row and align it with the rest of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make some space / gap between 2x col-sm-6 inside an row. Have tried some methods from earlier posts here from Stack Overflow, but none seem to make the right result.

What I have tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 contentpage3">            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 contentpage3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Well... this creates the right spacing, but then the left and right sides are not allign with the rest of the page content. To help you guys understand what I'm trying to explain, here is a picture.

[image]

Here you can see that the upper white content, the width is what I'm trying to keep for all the elements inside the page. I know its because the extra div I added, because the following code is producing the upper white content box you see in the picture, but then there is no spacing. Have also tried with col-md-5 and an offset of 2 but this creates too much spacing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 contentpage3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 contentpage3">
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This did not help solve it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

All `.col-*` elements should be inside row elements.

All `.col-*` elements should contain content, not be content.

```css
.example {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.example > .row > div {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.example .inside {
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid example">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="inside"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="inside"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="inside"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Updated my answer, `container` was just for the demo, you can use `container-fluid` if you want it to always fill the width of the parent. I only use it because it has (15px * 2) horizontal padding and is the bootstrap method of applying such padding.